# Customize Maven Lifecycle window in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to customize the `Lifecycle` view in JetBrains IntellijJ IDE?
Especially I'd like to hide most of them, as I only need `clean`, `package` and `install`. How can I remove the rest?

[image]

Comment: Try to use https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper instead

Answer (score 2):

The lifecycle in Maven is fixed. To my knowledge, it's not possible to customize this view but what you could do is the following:

Right click on each of "clean", "package" and "install" and do a "create ... run configuration". This will give you an extra item in the maven view with just those run configurations that you frequently use. You can then further customize them with specific arguments/params that you usually add.